# Compile-time error using Visual Studio 6

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++-6, visual-studio-6

First of all: it is some old code to be executed on some old machines, thus I'm forced to use the ancient Visual Studio 6 and can't simply update to a newer compiler. My problem: I have an array of a structure and try to statically initialize it. This works well with all modern compilers but VC6 complains for every member it is not compatible with the `struct` type.

The `struct` is defined as

```
struct instData
{
   char           m_IP[MAX_IP_LENGTH];
   unsigned short m_mode;
   int            m_sock;
   double         m_prev;
};
```

Static initialization looks like:

```
static struct instData data[MAX_HEAD_NUM+1]={
    {"",0,0,0.0},
    {"",0,0,0.0},
    ...
```

The error messages I get are:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char [1]' to 'struct instData'
    No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'struct instData'
    No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const int' to 'struct instData'
    No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const double' to 'struct instData'
    No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Means it complains for every member of the struct and all in first initialisation-line. So does anybody remember how such an initialisation should look like to work with VC6?

Comment: The code snippets you have posted looks good to me (should compile with absolutely any compiler). Have you tried compiling it with any other compiler - either a different version of VS or something else. I'm suspecting that you have something broken in the source itself.

Comment: Mats Petersson: using other compilers it works well, it is definitely a VC6 bug. Found a solution meanwhile at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11561375/array-of-structs-initialization-errors

Comment: @Elmi You may want to answer your own question.

Comment: Have you tried using GCC to compile it, in some old standards mode?